# Perl multi demonstration hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array

How can i create and add data into a hash `%grade_two` like this

```
$grade_two{Student}{Subject}{Test}{Score and edited Score} = ();
```

I do not want to hard code the data. i will stream into the variables through terminal `<STDIN>` `or` reading through a file.

`{Score and edited Score}`
 should take one or more entries (array) `if` any

do i need to use reference? or i can do without reference? 
Please give me an example of the code and explain your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected input stream?

Comment: 'Joe Ola' 'Math' 'Quiz1' '98'    
'ALex R' 'Math' 'Quiz1' '70'
'Ashley Brwown' 'English' 'Test1' '80' 'reviewed Score 86'  
'Joe Ola' 'Math' 'Quiz3' 80
'Ashley Brown' 'English' 'Mid-Term' '95'

Answer (score 0):

Use the @{} notation to "dereference" the hash reference to the array.  Note that
using "use strict" at the top of your perl file is good practice and will go a long
way to improving perl coding style :)

Try something like this:

```
use strict;

my %grade_two;

$grade_two{Student}{Subject}{Test}{'Score and edited Score'} = ();
push(@{$grade_two{Student}{Subject}{Test}{'Score and edited Score'}}, "123");
push(@{$grade_two{Student}{Subject}{Test}{'Score and edited Score'}}, "456");

1;
```